# How to call a different service from the interface in AEM osgi bundle?

Tags: java, xml, aem, osgi-bundle

We have a requirement due to which we need to replace a service class provided by AEM. for now we changed the xml entry but for the actual implementation we need to make a new xml file. but how to tell AEM that you should call the new xml.

Comment: what xml entry do you have in mind. Do you mean the JCR level file that retains the services configuration, or maybe the the OSGi descriptor. `call the new xml` sounds strange

Comment: well there is this XML which call s3dataservice class. i want it to call my new class so i changed the entry there but actually i have to write a new XML but i don't no how to tell AEM to refer this new xml file.

Comment: we need to change OSGI descriptor entry.